# C++: Is there an efficient way to use indices like pointers, syntactically?

Tags: c++, pointers

Here is my journey trying to get some zero-overhead syntactic convenience for a problem that I suspect pops up relatively often. I'm new to C++, so I hope that someone can offer me a better solution. All code given should compile and run under C++11. Note also that, although my solutions involve using exactly the syntax of pointers, I really am fine with just "as easy as using pointers."

I have some code that is using a network of objects with pointers to each other, as below. (My example here is just a linked-list for simplicity, but the actual structure is more complicated - a [half-edge mesh](http://www.openmesh.org/Daily-Builds/Doc/a00016.html).)

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
  int val;
  Node* next;
};

int main()
{
  Node* a = new Node();
  Node* b = new Node();

  a->val = 1;
  b->val = 2;
  a->next = b;

  std::cout << "Sum: " << a->val + a->next->val << std::endl;
}
```

For efficiency reasons, this code is being changed so that the objects are all stored in a central list, and accessed via index instead. (I understand that there are other options such as memorypools that could allow me to continue using actual pointers.)

*Notably,* I can't use iterators or pointers into the central list because the list will in general be getting modified a lot and (as I understand) pointers and iterators are likely to be invalidated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Node {
  int val;
  std::size_t next;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Node> nodeList {2};
  std::size_t a = 0;
  std::size_t b = 1;

  nodeList[a].val = 1;
  nodeList[b].val = 2;
  nodeList[a].next = b;

  std::cout << "Sum: " 
            << nodeList[a].val + nodeList[nodeList[a].next].val
            << std::endl;
}
```

Obviously, there's a syntactic cost to this change. In Scala, I could get around that with implicits. In C++, the most obvious thing I can think to do is create a wrapper object that knows both the index and the array, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, typename AofT = std::vector<T>>
struct IndexPtr {
  std::size_t index;
  AofT* collection;

  IndexPtr() = default;
  IndexPtr(std::size_t index, AofT& collection)
    : index(index), collection(&collection) 
  { /* no more initialization to do */ }

  T& operator*() { return (*collection)[index]; }
  T* operator->() { return &(*collection)[index]; }
};

struct Node {
  int val;
  IndexPtr<Node, std::vector<Node>> next;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Node> nodeList {2};
  auto a = IndexPtr<Node>(0, nodeList);
  auto b = IndexPtr<Node>(1, nodeList);

  a->val = 1;
  b->val = 2;
  a->next = b;

  std::cout << "Sum: " << a->val + a->next->val << std::endl;
}
```

However, now I'm storing an additional pointer with every index just for syntactic convenience. Unacceptable, especially since I have an eye to performance. So the only other thing I can think to do is kind of hackily simulate implicit parameters with a static class member:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, typename AofT = std::vector<T>>
struct IndexPtr {
  static AofT* collection;

  std::size_t index;

  IndexPtr() = default;
  IndexPtr(std::size_t index) : index(index) {}

  T& operator*() { return (*collection)[index]; }
  T* operator->() { return &(*collection)[index]; }
};

template<typename T, typename AofT>
AofT* IndexPtr<T, AofT>::collection = nullptr;

struct Node {
  int val;
  IndexPtr<Node, std::vector<Node>> next;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Node> nodeList {2};
  IndexPtr<Node>::collection = &nodeList;

  auto a = IndexPtr<Node>(0);
  auto b = IndexPtr<Node>(1);

  a->val = 1;
  b->val = 2;
  a->next = b;

  std::cout << "Sum: " << a->val + a->next->val << std::endl;
}
```

And that's the best that I've come up with, and it's a bit unsatisfying.

- Everything breaks horribly if you forget to initialize the `collection` variable before using any `IndexPtr`s.
- You can't have `IndexPtr`s using different arrays at the same time (easily), but I'm mostly OK with that.
- I don't know if there are any particular performance penalties to this approach.

Thoughts?

Comment: So does this whole thing boil down to having a linked list that can also be indexed like an array?

Comment: You could still use a pointer to elements in the vector, and increment it to obtain the next item. If you also want to allow new nodes to be added without invalidating existing entries then use `list` instead of `vector`, and use `list::iterator` instead of a pointer  (this is a class that wraps a pointer and provides the 'next' operation)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie @M.M The network structure here is just an example. That my example is a linked list is incidental. In fact I am implementing a [half-edge mesh](http://www.openmesh.org/Daily-Builds/Doc/a00016.html) representation of a polyhedron. It undergoes a large number of changes, so normal pointers will be invalidated. It isn't alright to use use `list` for pointer-chasing performance reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After considering Sergey Tachenov's answer for a while, I figured that a reasonable compromise can be made. There is a single wrapper class which knows both the index and the collection. It still has methods like `next()` which return another wrapper. However, we also allow using `operator*` and `operator->` to get at the raw, unwrapped values.

Thus, we don't have to use a complex scheme to support

```
a.next().next() = b;
```

Instead, we just typically use `->` at the end of a chain. So we can modify or use the value completely normally.

```
a.next()->next = b;
```

Here's the example code written using this method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Node {
    int val;
    std::size_t next;
};

class IndexPointer {
    std::size_t index;
    std::vector<Node>& collection;

public:
    IndexPointer(std::size_t index, std::vector<Node>& collection)
        : index(index), collection(collection)
    { /* done */ }

    inline operator std::size_t() {return index;}

    inline Node& operator*() {return collection[index];}
    inline Node* operator->() {return &collection[index];}
    inline IndexPointer next() {return IndexPointer((*this)->next, collection);}
};

class NodeList {
    std::vector<Node> nodes;

public:
    NodeList(std::size_t n) : nodes(n) {}
    inline IndexPointer operator[](std::size_t i) {return IndexPointer(i, nodes);}
};

int main()
{
    NodeList nodes {2};

    auto a = nodes[0];
    auto b = nodes[1];

    a->val = 1;
    a->next = b;
    a.next()->val = 2;

    std::cout << "Sum: " << a->val + a.next()->val << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. That's exactly what I was trying to do, only I didn't get it right and you did.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't like the `static` approach. You seem to realize that it's a huge problem when you have to use two or more collections and you never know that you won't. It's just a bad design.

After giving it a lot of thinking, I came up with this crazy solution:

```
class NodeList {
    friend class NodeReference;
    friend class NextReference;
private:
    struct Node {
        int val;
        std::size_t next;
    };
    std::vector<Node> nodes;
public:
    NodeList(std::size_t size) :
        nodes(size) {}
    inline NodeReference operator[](std::size_t index);
};

class NodeReference {
    friend class NodeList;
    friend class NextReference;
public:
    int &val() { return list.nodes[index].val; }
    inline NextReference next();
private:
    NodeList &list;
    std::size_t index;
    NodeReference(NodeList &list, std::size_t index) :
        list(list), index(index) {}
};

class NextReference {
    friend class NodeReference;
public:
    int &val()
    {
        return node.val();
    }
    NextReference operator=(NodeReference &node)
    {
        node.list.nodes[node.index].next = node.index;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    NodeReference &node;
    NextReference(NodeReference &node) :
        node(node) {}
};

inline NodeReference NodeList::operator[](std::size_t index)
{
    return NodeReference(*this, index);
}

inline NextReference NodeReference::next()
{
    return NextReference(*this);
}

int main() {
    NodeList nodeList(2);
    auto a = nodeList[0];
    auto b = nodeList[1];
    a.val() = 1;
    b.val() = 2;
    a.next() = b;

    std::cout << "Sum: " << a.val() + a.next().val() << std::endl;
}
```

But I still don't like it. Syntax-wise it's OK, I think, but that three-level referencing can be a performance issue and it's just seems too ugly. At first I was planning to have just one node reference created dynamically with `operator[]` so that you don't have to store a lot of list pointers in each node. But then I got confused how to implement the `next()` accessor. If it is to return a `NodeReference`, then how would `a.next() = b` work? Since `a.next()` references the next node now, how is its `operator=` supposed to change the `next` field of the `a` node?

**Update**

I went ahead and looked at the assembly generated by MSVS 2013 in release mode:

```
; 62   :    auto a = nodeList[0];
; 63   :    auto b = nodeList[1];
; 64   :    a.val() = 1;
; 65   :    b.val() = 2;
; 66   :    a.next() = b;
; 67   : 
; 68   :    std::cout << "Sum: " << a.val() + a.next().val() << std::endl;

    mov eax, DWORD PTR _nodeList$[esp+36]
    push    OFFSET ??$endl@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@@Z ; std::endl<char,std::char_traits<char> >
    mov DWORD PTR [eax], 1
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _nodeList$[esp+40]
    mov DWORD PTR [eax+8], 2
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _nodeList$[esp+40]
    mov DWORD PTR [eax+12], 1
```

So it looks like the compiler can actually fight its way through all that intermediate references and just assign the necessary values directly to where they belong. But the code still looks ugly inside and I can't get rid of the feeling that it can be made much easier, with less helper classes.

Comment: I really really like your ideas, thank you. After thinking about it for a while, I think I've come to a good compromise by using both `.next()` and `->next`. I've added it as an answer if you'd like to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

What about defining an int-based `NodePtr` class?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Node;

std::vector<Node> nodes;

struct NodePtr {
    int index = -1;
    operator bool() const { return index != -1; }
    Node& operator*() { return nodes[index]; }
    Node* operator->() { return &nodes[index]; }
};

struct Node {
    int val;
    NodePtr next;
};

int main()
{
    nodes.push_back({1});
    nodes.push_back({2});

    NodePtr a{0}, b{1};
    a->next = b;

    std::cout << "Sum: " << a->val + a->next->val << std::endl;
}
```

It basically adds an extra level of indirection (and it's known that this can solve any problem in computer science ... except the problem of having too many levels of indirection ;-) )

Comment: This is even worse than the static field approach because it essentially replaces the static field with a global variable.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov: a static is just a global with a funky name, there are no differences

Comment: The big difference is the namespace pollution.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov: just name the global `MyClass_static_var` and you will see the differences between that an `MyClass::static_var` are not that big (just some saving in typing when writing methods). C++ namespace partitioning doesn't really add anything essential... for example you cannot have two classes named `Point2d` in the same project unless you place them in different namespaces, but the namespaces must be explicitly specified in the source code. This makes for example close to  impossible to have a project using two versions of the same library at the same time...

Comment: I guess you can name it that way, but then you'll have to address it by that long name even inside the class it is used in. And if it's the only class that uses it, that will look ugly. A static variable, on the other hand, can have a short and meaningful name.